# Touch not working for mobile browser in twitter bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Template works fine in desktop browser but for mobile device its not response for touching specially in url and select options.

Its does not work in firefox and opera but in chrome its work for url but not some of select options.

You can check it form your mobile device http://templateninja.net/themes/arillo/v1.1/green/

Comment: I looked at it; pretty design. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, it *is* a bit odd behavior but having said that, I usually wrap things in rows (to easily add control) when building forms with Bootstrap. This will fix your issue.

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Australia</option>
                    <option>Indonesia</option>
                    <option>Japan</option>
                    <option>South Korea</option>
                    <option>China</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bedroom">Bedroom</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- break -->
        <!-- Your other form fields -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Primary its work for one my form, Hope wrapping row will fix this issue.